# Getting a Variety of Runtime Errors When Consuming My (Packaged) Angular Library’s Components in Another Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm trying to consume my own Angular component library in another Angular app (in another repo). I've gotten past any compile-time errors, but now runtime errors show up when including the (declared and exported) components of the library. The confusing thing is that the errors vary per component.

- With a simple "external link" component I get "TypeError: getLView() is null"
- With a wrapper around a text input I get "TypeError: tView is null"
- With a somewhat more advanced list view I get "Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`"

That last one is the only error that seems to be somewhat common.

The library('s `ng build` output) is installed as a dependency in the consuming repo/app's package.json - more specifically via a [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths), i.e. like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "atoms-lib": "file:../path/to/different/repo/dist/atoms-lib"
},
```

The library's module is imported in the app's AppModule.

```
import { AtomsLibModule } from 'atoms-lib';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AtomsLibModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There are obviously tons of other config files involved, and I'm happy to share any specific ones you think might be the culprit. A few more things I have already considered:

- The Angular versions of the library and the consuming app match (Angular ^15.2.0).
- The problem persists both in partial and full Ivy compilation mode (for the library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess the answer was hiding in plain sight, in [an issue thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813) I had already read several times. In the consuming app's tsconfig.json, under `compilerOptions`/`paths`, add `"@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ],`. I.e. make it look like this.

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ],
      ...
    },
 ...
}
```

Why this is necessary? No flipping clue.